# How to get all children of a document library using CMIS

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, cmis

I am new to DOTCMIS in Sharepoint On prem 2013. I am able to get the sharepoint document library using atom pub with below code.

```
parameters[SessionParameter.User] = "*****";
                parameters[SessionParameter.Password] = "******";

                // connection settings
                parameters[SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://zeus:18439/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/cd4e6a20-32dd-46f5-96a8-00ef7b754ec2?getRepositoryInfo";
                parameters[SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.AtomPub;
                parameters[SessionParameter.RepositoryId] = "cd4e6a20-32dd-46f5-96a8-00ef7b754ec2";
                parameters[SessionParameter.AuthenticationProviderClass] = "DotCMIS.Binding.NtlmAuthenticationProvider";

                // create session
                ISession session = factory.CreateSession(parameters);
                migrateRepos = factory.GetRepositories(parameters);
```

I want to loop through all children (Sub folders & Items inside folders)..How to achieve this...glad for any help

Answer (score 2):

No need for queries.

Just use `GetChildren`, and check the type of each children to decide whether to recurse or not:

```
foreach (ICmisObject cmisObject in remoteFolder.GetChildren(operationContext))
{
    if (cmisObject is DotCMIS.Client.Impl.Folder)
    {
        // It is a CMIS folder.
        IFolder remoteSubFolder = (IFolder)cmisObject;
        // TODO Recurse
    }
    else if (cmisObject is DotCMIS.Client.Impl.Document)
    {
        // It is a CMIS document.
        IDocument remoteDocument = (IDocument)cmisObject;
        // TODO do something with it.
    }
    else
    {
        // It is a CMIS link or something else.
    }
}
```

Real-life example:
https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync/blob/master/CmisSync.Lib/Sync/CrawlStrategy.cs#L164

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get this done by below code..

```
IItemEnumerable<IQueryResult> Fileresults = session.Query("SELECT * FROM cmis:document", false);
 if (Folderresults.TotalNumItems > 0)
                {
                    arrFolderPaths = new string[Folderresults.TotalNumItems + 1];
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (IQueryResult cmisObject1 in Folderresults)
                    {   
                        string objectId = ((DotCMIS.Data.Impl.PropertyData)(cmisObject1.GetPropertyById("cmis:objectId"))).Values[0].ToString();
                        ICmisObject cmisObject = session.GetObject(objectId);
                        IFileableCmisObject fileableCmisObject = cmisObject as IFileableCmisObject;
                        paths = fileableCmisObject.Paths;
                        arrFolderPaths[i] = paths[0].ToString();
                        CreateFolderPathsInDestSP(DestCtx, DestinationlistName.RootFolder, arrFolderPaths[i]);
                        i++;
                    }

                }
```